# Will sending User-IDs to Google Analytics replace existing Client IDs? Or will it count as a new user entirely?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have Google Analytics set up, and have been using it without sending in User Ids for over a year. I have thousands of users that we're tracking, and now we'd like to start tracking users by USER-ID.

If I begin sending in the user id using analytics.js, will Google Analytics count the user as a new user, even if the user is an actual return user to the app?

I want to avoid this if possible. I'm hoping GA is smart enough to simply replace the existing client id with the user id info, that way existing users aren't tracked as new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Client ID will still be collected and sent to Google Analytics regardless of you sending User ID.